# Why is this SQL delete statement not working?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL delete statement. The syntax works and the values are all correct, but allways when I execute it, it ask me if I really want to delete 0 rows.

```
delete * from database1 where (database1.Name = 'Alain' and database1.Grund = 'Defekt' and database1.Gerätename = 'Beamer' and database1.Ausleihdatum = '9/2/2019' and database1.Rückgabedatum = '15/3/2019')
```

I don't get an error or something else, it just ask me if I want to delete 0 rows, but that makes no sense, because the values are all correct. I checked them like 5 times. I tried to make the statement without the *,

```
delete from database1 where (database1.Name = 'Alain' and database1.Grund = 'Defekt' and database1.Gerätename = 'Beamer' and database1.Ausleihdatum = '9/2/2019' and database1.Rückgabedatum = '15/3/2019')
```

but that doesn't work too. Here it is the same scenario...

I wan't that the delete statement works the right way, but I don't know how.

Comment: You need to use the alias or table names with delete statements you can't use only the wildchar (`*`).. That said `delete database1.* from database1`  should also work..

Comment: Try to do select to check if your conditions are met: `SELECT * from database1 where (database1.Name = 'Alain' and database1.Grund = 'Defekt' and database1.Gerätename = 'Beamer' and database1.Ausleihdatum = '9/2/2019' and database1.Rückgabedatum = '15/3/2019')`

Comment: try this delete from database1 where  Name = 'Alain' and Grund = 'Defekt' and Gerätename = 'Beamer' and Ausleihdatum = '9/2/2019' and Rückgabedatum = '15/3/2019' if this is wrong then i think you must check your condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was a relation that I recently added to an other table. So the "Gerätename" value was still the right one in the table I wanted to delete something, but not in the other Table...